# Laravel, model->save() does not return new id (in some cases)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, homestead, laravel-vapor

When i run the following code the Order does get saved in the database. But the resulting `id` of the save is `0` in some cases. In the database the Order has a normal id of say 100,101.

```
        $this->order->save(); // new order not in database yet
        //dd($this->order);

        $id = $this->order->id;
        if ($id === 0  || $id === null) {
            throw new CreateOrderFailedException('Order ID = null');
        }
```

The above code, works locally on Homestead sandbox. When I push the code to staging and production (which are both Vapor environments). The save function always returns an `$order->id` of `0`  i am at a loss as of why. Again locally this works. What could possibly be different on a vapor environment which would break this? Same php version, same laravel version. Same (session)caching, same database.

The `dd` statements show a fresh new ID localy but `0` on the vapor (staging/production) environments. Any idea's would be very welcome.

I tried:

- `$id = DB::table('orders')->insertGetId([atts])`
- `$this->order = new Order([atts]); $this->order->save()`
- `$this->order->create([atts])`

Result stays the same (works perfectly localy, not once deployed on Vapor)

Edit, made an extremely dirty fix which for now solves the issue

```
        $id = DB::select('SELECT id FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');

        if ($id === null || $id[0]->id === 0) {
            throw new CreateOrderFailedException('Order ID = null');
        }

        $this->order->id = $id[0]->id;
        $this->addProductsToOrder($id[0]->id);
        $this->updateStatusAndCreateNote($id[0]->id);
```

So working without the Model class seems to retrieve the latest ID correctly. But if someone can elaborate on this Eloquent returning id = 0 issue I am all ears.

As requested the `dd` of the attributes that are put into the save function.

Local

```
array:19 [
  "order_nr" => "OR2112-0000000109"
  "is_weekly_order" => 1
  "type" => 0
  "user_id" => 540
  "admin_id" => null
  "sales_id" => null
  "shipping_costs" => 0
  "status" => 0
  "reference" => null
  "shipping_method" => 3
  "signed_shipping" => false
  "country_id" => "NL"
  "is_demo" => false
  "comment" => null
  "shipping_address_id" => 679
  "billing_address_id" => 679
  "is_master_key_system" => null
  "created_at" => Carbon\Carbon @1640370798 {#1673
    #endOfTime: false
    #startOfTime: false
    #constructedObjectId: "000000007fdf7f5c0000000072fb8804"
    #localMonthsOverflow: null
    #localYearsOverflow: null
    #localStrictModeEnabled: null
    #localHumanDiffOptions: null
    #localToStringFormat: null
    #localSerializer: null
    #localMacros: null
    #localGenericMacros: null
    #localFormatFunction: null
    #localTranslator: null
    #dumpProperties: array:3 [
      0 => "date"
      1 => "timezone_type"
      2 => "timezone"
    ]
    #dumpLocale: null
    #dumpDateProperties: null
    date: 2021-12-24 19:33:18.488342 Europe/Amsterdam (+01:00)
  }
  "updated_at" => Carbon\Carbon @1640370798 {#1640
    #endOfTime: false
    #startOfTime: false
    #constructedObjectId: "000000007fdf7fbd0000000072fb8804"
    #localMonthsOverflow: null
    #localYearsOverflow: null
    #localStrictModeEnabled: null
    #localHumanDiffOptions: null
    #localToStringFormat: null
    #localSerializer: null
    #localMacros: null
    #localGenericMacros: null
    #localFormatFunction: null
    #localTranslator: null
    #dumpProperties: array:3 [
      0 => "date"
      1 => "timezone_type"
      2 => "timezone"
    ]
    #dumpLocale: null
    #dumpDateProperties: null
    date: 2021-12-24 19:33:18.488374 Europe/Amsterdam (+01:00)
  }
]
```

Vapor:

```
array:19 [
  "order_nr" => "OR2112-0000000079"
  "is_weekly_order" => 1
  "type" => 0
  "user_id" => 570
  "admin_id" => null
  "sales_id" => null
  "shipping_costs" => 0
  "status" => 0
  "reference" => null
  "shipping_method" => 3
  "signed_shipping" => false
  "country_id" => "NL"
  "is_demo" => false
  "comment" => null
  "shipping_address_id" => 550
  "billing_address_id" => 551
  "is_master_key_system" => null
  "created_at" => Carbon\Carbon @1640371111 {#2036
    #endOfTime: false
    #startOfTime: false
    #constructedObjectId: "0000000003fd91d000000000742f9e90"
    #localMonthsOverflow: null
    #localYearsOverflow: null
    #localStrictModeEnabled: null
    #localHumanDiffOptions: null
    #localToStringFormat: null
    #localSerializer: null
    #localMacros: null
    #localGenericMacros: null
    #localFormatFunction: null
    #localTranslator: null
    #dumpProperties: array:3 [
      0 => "date"
      1 => "timezone_type"
      2 => "timezone"
    ]
    #dumpLocale: null
    #dumpDateProperties: null
    date: 2021-12-24 19:38:31.570906 Europe/Amsterdam (+01:00)
  }
  "updated_at" => Carbon\Carbon @1640371111 {#2025
    #endOfTime: false
    #startOfTime: false
    #constructedObjectId: "0000000003fd91cd00000000742f9e90"
    #localMonthsOverflow: null
    #localYearsOverflow: null
    #localStrictModeEnabled: null
    #localHumanDiffOptions: null
    #localToStringFormat: null
    #localSerializer: null
    #localMacros: null
    #localGenericMacros: null
    #localFormatFunction: null
    #localTranslator: null
    #dumpProperties: array:3 [
      0 => "date"
      1 => "timezone_type"
      2 => "timezone"
    ]
    #dumpLocale: null
    #dumpDateProperties: null
    date: 2021-12-24 19:38:31.571011 Europe/Amsterdam (+01:00)
  }
]
```

Even here i cannot notice anything substantial as i was already thinking. The only other possible explanation i have is that vapor does some things async in relation to the database. Other then that i am out of clues.

Comment: is the id auto incremental? what are code above `$this->order->save();` this line? i mean to say, how have you declared `$this->order` object?

Comment: yes auto_increment, made with `$table->bigIncrements('id')`  `$this->order = new Order([attributes]); // creation` code works locally not on vapor

Comment: Do you see the record in the database with an id set after the save()?

Comment: see first line of question

Comment: are you sure, you are not setting the `id` manually? in that case, you have to use this `public $incrementing = false;` in your model.

Comment: yes i am sure, i also tried it with `$id = DB::table('orders')->insertGetId([atts])` , and this also return 0 for the `id` for some reason Eloquent really does only want to return `0` for the ID.

Comment: If you post your `Order` model and a dump `dd([...])` of the attributes being used to fill the model, perhaps we can rule some things out.

Comment: it's the same, remember i said: it works locally, the issue appears after deployment on vapor environment. the dd of the model itself is the same on localhost and on staging/production, only difference is the id is always `0`

Comment: hold on a sec i will dd the attributes and update the post

Comment: @matticustard i have added the dd's

Comment: Thank you. I do not see an issue with the attributes, but it's helpful to be able to view and verify. I had asked about the `Order` model as I was curious whether you have defined any values for `$primary_key`, `$incrementing`, etc. within the model — just to rule out potential issues there — or whether you have defined any model events (`creating`, `saving`, etc.) that could be interfering with normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday we also encounter the same type of issue. Locally everything is working fine but in a production environment after saving the model, we don't get the id attribute even though the created_at and updated_at attributes are in the modal. But after running the composer update the issue also starts arriving in local environments.

This issue is due to an update of laravel/framework version from 9.26.1 to v9.31.0.

We solve this issue by downgrading laravel/framework to 9.26.1.

Comment: So you still do not know which version was problematic, and you only know which is not?

Comment: we figure out that this issue is due to the laravel/framework version update to v9.31.0.